# arduino disambungkan ke konputer nyala dan mati lagi

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

mengapa ketika saya menyambungkan arduino ke komputer saya, lampu indikator hidup menyala lalu mati seketika dan arduino tidak berfungsi, tolong bantuannya

Saya berharap arduino saya dapat kembali hidup karena ini untuk tugas sekolah.